# Calcular diagonal de prisma rectangular

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando en `WindowsForms` calcular partes de ciertas figuras pero tengo un problema.

Necesito sacar la diagonal del prisma rectangular y la fórmula es la siguiente.

**LadoLargo** a la **2** **+** **LadoCorto** a la **2** **+** **Altura** a la **2** y a este resultado le saco raíz cuadrada ese seria el resultado de la diagonal del prisma

Mi código esta de la siguiente manera.

```
double resultado, diagonal;
resultado = LadoLargo * LadoLargo + LadoCorto *LadoCorto + Altura * Altura;
diagonal = Math.Sqrt(resultado);
return diagonal;
```

Desearía saber si hay otra manera mas corta que mi código como `Math.Pow()` o alguna otra ya que me dicen que no declare tanta variable muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Como tú dices podrías usar `Math.Pow()` para acortar la línea del cálculo. Además podrías ahorrarte la variable diagonal ya que su única función es la de ser devuelta, por lo tanto una versión más acortada de tu código podría ser algo así:

```
double resultado = Math.Pow(LadoLargo,2) + Math.Pow(LadoCorto,2)+ Math.Pow(Altura,2);
return Math.Sqrt(resultado);
```

Si lo que quieres es todavía hacerlo más corto podrías incluso meter la línea del cálculo dentro de `Math.Sqrt(...)` aunque no te lo recomiendo ya que la dificultad de su debug aumenta.
Un saludo

Comment: Estuvo genial gracias

Comment: @MaiikolMorales Si te ha servido como respuesta deberías marcarla como tal para que otros usuarios puedan aprovecharla